# How do I dynamically remove an item from my wishlist after I drag the item into the trash bin?

Tags: php, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/L9tba27k/3/

I only have Jquery code in there. But how would I dynamically remove the content off the wishlist when I move it into the bin?

This is my code to remove/add wishlist without dragging it into the bin:

```
<a href="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>category/wishlist_delete?id=<?php echo $model->wish{0}->id; ?>"> ADD TO WISHLIST </a>

<a href="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>category/wishlist_post?id=<?php echo $products{0}->id; ?>"> REMOVE FROM WISHLIST </a>
```

P.S: The SITE_URL is just my company's framework code to access the files

Comment: `<a onclick="this.parent.removeChild(this);" ...>`?

Comment: put the <a onclick="this.parent.removeChild(this);" ...> on the Jquery code? I mean I want to remove it from the wishlist count, not just simply remove the image

Comment: this'd just remove the `<a>` node from your dom tree. you'd still need to fire off a delete notice to the server.